# Appending element of one list to sub-list of another list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Suppose I have the following lists:

```
l1 = [['a'],['b'],['c'],['d']]
l2 = [1,2,3,4]
```

I want to make a new list where each element of second list would be appended to each sub-list of `l1` the desired out should be:

```
[['a',1],['b',2],['c',3],['d',4]]
```

yet when I do `[k for i in zip(l1, l2) for k in i]`, I get the following:

```
[['a'], 1, ['b'], 2, ['c'], 3, ['d'], 4]
```

which is not desired I wonder what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the nested loop, you're unpacking the sublists. You could use list concatenation instead:

```py
out = [i+[j] for i,j in zip(l1, l2)]
```

Output:

```py
[['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3], ['d', 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify `l1` in place:

```
l1 = [['a'],['b'],['c'],['d']]
l2 = [1,2,3,4]

for x,y in zip(l1, l2):
    x.append(y)
```

output:

```
[['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3], ['d', 4]]
```